# pvmove - moving a sub-range of physical extents from a segment to an unallocated PE range

Tags: lvm

Is it okay to move a sub-range of physical extents from a segment at the end of a physical volume to an unallocated range in the middle of the physical volume? (The sub-range has the same number of extents as the unallocated range.)

For example, I'd like to move the unallocated extents, which are extents 50688-50943, to the end of physical volume by moving the last 256 extents of the last segment to extents 50688-50943:

```
# pvmove --test --alloc anywhere /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:60694-60949 /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:50688-50943
  TEST MODE: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be (de)activated.
```

Here is the extent information of the physical volume:

```
# pvs -v --segments
  PV                    VG   Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree Start SSize  LV   Start Type   PE Ranges                        
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g     0   3328 root     0 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:0-3327     
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g  3328   2560 swap     0 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:3328-5887  
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g  5888  43520 home     0 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:5888-49407 
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 49408   1280 root 13334 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:49408-50687
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 50688    256          0 free                                    
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 50944   1536 root 11798 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:50944-52479
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 52480    256 root 11542 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:52480-52735
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 52736    256 root 11286 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:52736-52991
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 52992    256 root 11030 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:52992-53247
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 53248   2560 root  8470 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:53248-55807
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 55808   1280 root  7190 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:55808-57087
  /dev/mapper/cryptdisk lvg  lvm2 a--  <238.09g 1.00g 57088   3862 root  3328 linear /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:57088-60949
```

Comment: `pvmove` will split/merge segments accordingly, so it should work fine. Are you planning to shrink the PV?

Comment: @frostschutz yes, the reason behind this is to shrink the PV by around 1 GiB. I'm working on an image of the whole disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all used sector to the end, to the first sector free:

```bash
pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/mapper/cryptdisk:50944-60949/dev/mapper/cryptdisk:50688-60693
```